# Is freelancing as a Data Scientist a viable option?

Tags: careers, freelancing

Nowadays people can freelance as web designers, app developers amongst other jobs which relate to creating a piece of software.

Can a Data Scientist be added to this list? If so, where would they get projects to work on from?

Since it has become popular recently and bigger organisations tend to use Data Science as a means to make smarter decisions. However, smaller organisations may not have one due to financial costs or not realising a benefits of a Data Scientist. They are more likely to have a website so a web designer is more important to them to create an attractive website (aesthetically and functionally) to generate business.

Comment: You can freelance at anything if you are good at marketing yourself. However, given the nature of data science, I would guess it would be more effective to market yourself as an expert consultant (assuming you actually are not entry level). If you are entry level, go to work for companies until you have at least ten years of experience and then become a consultant.

Comment: A data scientist shouldn't have to ask this question.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, definitely.

Clearly you are right. The need to use Data Science grows with the size of an organization. Actually a two-person company is very unlikely to even have such a huge amount of data, to enable them to perform Data Science.

Also larger organizations normally don't hire a ***freelancer***. Larger organizations hire ***consultants***. But in your special case, I would argue, that it is largely just a matter of wording.

Both words mean being an indepedent contractor instead of an    permanent employee, but being a consultant implies a larger portion of counseling and expert advice, then you would normally expect from a freelancer.

Both of them get their customers in the same way: Connections, personal references and direct acquisition.

**To sum up:** If you have a certain expert knowledge in Data Science which enables you to effectively counsel companies in the use of Data Science to help them grow their business, there is no reason that stops you from becoming a Data Science Consultant.